# CRM 2011 Plugin (Message: Delete, Pre-validation) Warning on Multi-Delete

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

When I delete a MarketingList(A) i have a plugin that fires and retrieve another Marketing List(B) using a Guid stored in an attribute on MarketingList(A).

If I select the MarketingList(A) and delete it, the MarketingList(B) is deleted correcly. But when I select both (A & B) or all the records on the grid I have a warning:
"An error has occured. The selected action was not completed for one or more records". 
After the warning the records are deleted.

Any help is appreciated!

## Plugin:

```
Message: **Delete**<br>
PrimaryEntity: **list**<br>
Stage of Execution: **Pre-Validation**.
```

## Code:

```
if (context.MessageName == "Delete")
{
    using (var crm = new XrmServiceContext(service))
    {
        List listToDelete = crm.ListSet.Where(p => p.Id == context.PrimaryEntityId).SingleOrDefault();
        List retrievedList = crm.ListSet.Where(p => p.Id == new Guid(listToDelete.tph_WitnessMarketingListID)).SingleOrDefault();
        if (retrievedList == null) return;
        crm.DeleteObject(retrievedList);
        crm.SaveChanges();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you will be able to avoid this (at least with your current design).

I believe you are correct that the problem is the grid trying to delete something which has already been deleted.

I suspect the grid control isn’t checking to see if the record exists before trying to delete it. I wouldn’t expect it to; it's just been given a list of things to delete, it seems reasonable to assume they still exist.

I can see a couple of ways to fix this.

1. Use a workflow to delete the record, this way it should always run after the grid has finished its work.
2. Make your plugin run asynchronously on the post, again this way it should always run after the grid has finished its work.
3. Remove the delete button from the grid, and add a custom ribbon button with behaviour to check if the record exists before deleting.

As a side note, are you aware the plugin you have implemented will perform the same behaviour as a cascading relationship? If you set the relationship to cascade deletes, then you don’t need any code.

Comment: Thank you James, i think i will go with the Cascades Deletes options as you mentioned in your post.

Comment: Cascade delete might suffer from the same problem. I was just pointing out that you are implementing logic that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only storing the string of the id of B in the field (tph_WitnessMarketingListID) of A. It could be possible that B was deleted before A, hence the delete could have failed. Try debugging your plugin to see the line on which it is failing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i debugged and there's no exception, the records are deleted after the warning. I agree with your point, i think it's the behavior of the Grid when trying to delete something already deleted. Other suggestions?